# Firebase Register Topic C# responseObject.Success return null (The collection returned no results)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to register firebase Topic using fresh generated Token And GUID UserID. and i'm calling the Methode from MVC Test Class.

But as a result im getting Success Null. i dont know what does it mean actually.

Please help! this is my code :

```
public bool RegisterTopic(string userIdentifierForAllDevices, string singleDeviceNoticationKey)
    {
        var serverApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["firebaseServerKey"];
        var firebaseGoogleUrl = $"https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/{singleDeviceNoticationKey}/rel/topics/{userIdentifierForAllDevices}";

        var httpClient = new WebClient();
        httpClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "key=" + serverApiKey);

        object data = new {};
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        var responsebytes = httpClient.UploadData(firebaseGoogleUrl, "POST", byteArray);
        string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
        dynamic responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responsebody);

        return responseObject.success == "1";
    }
```

[image: Return result.Success Null]

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved that by using:

> Device Group Notification

Instead of the Topic and that works perfectly.

```
 public void AddDeviceToGroup(string user, string notificationKey, string registrationId)
    {
        DeviceGroupData deviceGroupData = new DeviceGroupData();
        deviceGroupData.Operation = "add";
        deviceGroupData.NotificationKeyName = user; 
        deviceGroupData.NotificationKey = notificationKey;
        deviceGroupData.RegistrationIds.Add(registrationId);

        DeviceGroupPost(deviceGroupData);
    }

 private string DeviceGroupPost(DeviceGroupData deviceGroupData)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(deviceEndPoint);

            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deviceGroupData));

            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "key=" + firebaseServerKey);
            request.Headers.Add("project_id", senderId);
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            stream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                CustomLogger.LogError(null,"Failed to" + deviceGroupData.Operation + "Token to/from the deviceGroup for the userId" + deviceGroupData.NotificationKeyName);
                return null;
            }

            stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string info = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            var jsondata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeviceGroupData>(info);

            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();

            return jsondata.NotificationKey;
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            CustomLogger.LogError(x, "Failed to" + deviceGroupData.Operation + "Token to/from the deviceGroup for the userId" + deviceGroupData.NotificationKeyName);
            return null;
        }
```